# How do can I creating and use a custom fields in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am new to django and building a kinda of a package (Shipments) based app in Django and I have these models,

```
class ShippingLocation(models.Model):
    latitude = models.IntegerField()
    longitude = models.IntegerField()

class Shipping (models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    location = models.ForeignKey(ShippingLocation , default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE )

class Package(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    to =  models.ForeignKey(Shipping, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
```

this work okay for now but I wonder if can be able to remove the `ShippingLocation` model and use a custom field instead of at the location field in the Shipping model? If yes how do I create custom fields and how do I implement them?

so I have something like

```
class Shipping (models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    location = models.DictionaryField()
```

and I get rid of the `ShippingLocationModel`

Comment: What do you mean by custom field? What would it look like?

Comment: I have just edited the question

Comment: If you are using prostgres this is a good thing to know https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/, otherwise check this out. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-model-fields/
Personally i think that the current approach is the best (i know this does not answer your question, just some feedback)

Comment: am using sqlite

Comment: Django supports jsonfield https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield
but I do not recommend it.

Comment: jsonfield is postgres specific.

Answer (score -1):

This should be work:

1. delete the SQLite database
2. change the model
3. then run the migrate command

Comment: HIs question is about creating a "dictionary field" not how to run a migrate command. And fyi you should not delete any database whatsoever. The right process would be to make the change, run makemigrations and the run migrate (without deleting anything). the whole point of migrations is to be able to change db schema without losing any data.